# Debug Angular build in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular-pwa

Since I'm developing a PWA app with angular, I use a watched build that always rebuilds my code if I change anything:

```
ng build --output-path dist --watch
```

That works fine.

I can also run a lite-server via command line to run the build results from the dist-folder:

```
lite-server
```

As result, I can see the built app on localhost:3000

But I don't have any debugging from my Visual Studio Code. If I extend the `launch.json` with a configuration that launched the server:

```
{
    "name": "Launch via NPM",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "run-script", "runServer"
    ]
}
```

where `runServer` is a script in my package.json just containing "lite-server".
I can select and run this configuration. It starts the server and opens even the browser. But there is still no debugging in Visual Studio Code like stopping on breakpoints.

I'm wondering, if this possible at all: To build the angular code in a dist-folder and not just "serve" it with `ng serve`. Using `ng serve` and the default chrome launch configuraiton in VSC works well for debugging Angular. But then I do not have the PWA capabilities.

But maybe someone has an idea that works.

Comment: The type definitely should not be `node`. It should be `browser`... Also for `run-script` I would use `ng serve`

Comment: But if I use 'ng serve' it don't use the 'ng build' results in the dist folder as needed for an pwa app installation/update ...?

Comment: Still, you are not connecting to node, but to web browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to run the `ng build` development configuration:

```
ng build --output-path dist --watch --configuration development
```

Where development is the default one defined in `angular.json`:

```
 "development": {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true
        }
```

The key is `sourceMap` - in this constellation, the PWA can be debugged in Visual Studio Code with no changes at launch.json in comparison to the non-pwa ng serve scenario.